# Why there is at most one fraction $d/r$ with $r<n$ and $q \geq 2n^2$ such that $|\frac{c}{q}-\frac{d}{r}|\leq \frac{1}{2q}$

Tags: number-theory, factoring, fractions

I am reading a research paper on 'Factoring Algorithms for Quantum Computation' by Peter W. Shor. In this paper there is written somewhere :-

(n,c,d,q,r are all positive integers)

> $$\frac{-r}{2} \le rc-dq \le \frac{r}{2} \tag{6.9}$$ Dividing by
>   rq and rearranging the terms gives
>   $$\left|\frac{c}{q}-\frac{d}{r}\right|\le \frac{1}{2q} \tag{6.10}$$ We
>   know $c$ and $q$. Because $q \ge 2n^2$, there is at most one fraction
>   $d/r$ with $r < n$ that satisfies the above inequality.

Here i didn't understand that what is meant by only one $d/r$, why it can not be more than one.
My approach:-
Let $q=2n^2$ and $r=n-a$ then eq. $(6.10)$ becomes 
$$\left|\frac{c}{2n^2}-\frac{d}{n-a}\right|\le\frac{1}{4n^2}$$
Now since $$\frac{1}{2n^2}=2\times \frac{1}{4n^2}$$ so $d/(n-a)$ has to be $(1/4n^2)+something$

From here things got messy, and i started feeling that I'm going in the wrong direction.I want to understand why there will be only one fraction $d/r$ satisfying the foretold inequality?
Please Help !

Comment: I started looking into this with not much hope, I blocked, I tried, I pulled my hair, and I just now noticed you wrote $n,c,d,q,r\ge 0$.

I stop now, I'm sure someone will find your answer, it's just too hard for me. I know it was my fault for not reading but i suggest you edit your post to make all integers positive a little bit more visible. Cheers

Comment: what do you know about $c$? You only have to show that the distance between any two such numbers (which is at least $1/r$ is bigger than $1/q$. Without knowing something about $c$ this does not seem to be true.

Comment: As i can extract from the paper $c$ seems to be smaller than $q$